# Xamarin form: Am I putting to much TrackEvent in the code and does TrackError can be used in non catch statement

Tags: xamarin, azure-application-insights, diagnostics

I am not sure am i going on the right track. I have a put a lot of Track Event in this method to track user flow. Anyone give some idea whether I am putting too much.

```
try
            {
                #region AppCenter Analytics
                Diagnostic.TrackEvent("Start Refreshing Token",
                    new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                        { "Username",  username}
                    });
                #endregion

                #region AppCenter Diagnostics --Empty
                #endregion

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(refreshToken))
                {
                    #region AppCenter Analytics
                    Diagnostic.TrackEvent("Empty Refreshed Token",
                        new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                        { "Username",  username}
                        });
                    #endregion

                    #region AppCenter Diagnostics --Empty
                    #endregion

                    return new CommonResult<TokenModel>()
                    {
                        Data = null,
                        Code = (int) ErrorCode.ErrorRefreshTokenEmpty,
                        IsSuccess = false,
                        ErrorMessage = string.Empty,
                        Error = new ErrorData(new Exception("Refresh token is empty."), new string[] { })
                    };
                }

                #region AppCenter Analytics
                Diagnostic.TrackEvent("Get Discovery Endpoint",
                    new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                        { "Username",  username}
                    });
                #endregion

                #region Diagnostics -- Empty
                #endregion

                var disco = await GetDiscoveryResponseAsync();

                if (disco.IsError)
                {
                    #region AppCenter Analytics
                    Diagnostic.TrackEvent("Error Discovery Endpoint",
                        new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                        { "Username",  username}
                        });
                    #endregion

                    #region Diagnostics -- Empty
                    #endregion

                    return new CommonResult<TokenModel>() 
                    { 
                        Data = null, 
                        IsSuccess = false,
                        Code = (int) ErrorCode.ErrorDiscoveryEndpoint,
                        ErrorMessage = string.Empty
                    };
                }

                #region AppCenter Analytics
                Diagnostic.TrackEvent("Get Refresh Token Endpoint",
                    new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                        { "Username",  username},
                        { "Endpoint", disco.TokenEndpoint}
                    });
                #endregion

                #region Diagnostics -- Empty
                #endregion

                var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                var response = await httpClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(new RefreshTokenRequest()
                {
                    Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,

                    ClientId = clientId,
                    ClientSecret = clientSecret,
                    Scope = scope,
                    RefreshToken = refreshToken
                });

                if (response.IsError)
                {
                    #region AppCenter Analytics
                    Diagnostic.TrackEvent("Error getting refresh token",
                        new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                            { "Username",  username },
                            { "Endpoint", disco.TokenEndpoint } 
                        });
                    #endregion

                    #region Diagnostics -- Empty
                    #endregion

                    return new CommonResult<TokenModel>()
                    {
                        Data = null,
                        IsSuccess = false,
                        Code = (int)ErrorCode.ErrorRefreshToken,
                        ErrorMessage = string.Empty
                    };
                }

                var data = new TokenModel()
                {
                    ExpiresIn = response.ExpiresIn.ToString(),
                    TokenType = response.TokenType,
                    AccessToken = response.AccessToken,
                    RefreshToken = response.RefreshToken
                };

                return new CommonResult<TokenModel>() { Data = data, IsSuccess = true, ErrorMessage = String.Empty };
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                #region AppCenter Analytics
                Diagnostic.TrackEvent("Error Getting Refresh Token",
                    new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                        { "Username",  username}
                    });
                #endregion

                #region Diagnostics -- Empty
                Diagnostic.TrackErrorRequired(exception,
                    new Dictionary<string, string> {
                        { "Username", username },
                    });
                #endregion

                return new CommonResult<TokenModel>()
                {
                    Data = null,
                    IsSuccess = false,
                    Code = (int) ErrorCode.ErrorRefreshTokenUnknown,
                    ErrorMessage = string.Empty
                };
            }
        }
```

Also inside the if-statement which have error when executing previous code, should I call Crashes.TrackError to track the error or should not use Crashes.TrackError since it's not a crashed.

If shouldn't use Crashes.TrackError, what is the best practices to log those errors. I can placed in TrackEvent but there are limit of characters can be passed on as properties.

Answer (score 0):

`TrackError` is specifically for tracking caught exceptions.

Comment: Yes i understand. so is no good to place it in those remote call which return errors but not an exception.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question.  I think this is really a matter of opinion, if creating an exception object to track the errors is useful to you, then do it.  There is no clear correct answer to this.

Comment: Thank you... This is my first time using this tools not sure if putting too much. If I put trackEvent on top of the method, i will only know user is executing the method but nothing more